# graphic problems with chicken invaders and epsxe

Tags: windows, wine, games, emulation

My windows vista keeps rebooting on the green bar load screen so i got Ubuntu 12.04 and installed it but i had trouble running my games and apps from vista until some guy on line told me to get wine which i did and my apps started loading but when i tried to run dawn of war dark crusade it launched but did not display in full screen (no biggie) the ubuntu side bar was still there on the side and so was the task bar (if thats what its called) at the top. But after the cut screen the loading page with all the logos appeared and the game closed ( not cool) i kept trying until I finally gave up and run chicken invaders which launched properly but had some graphic bugs on the menu then i tried to run epsxe and play final fantasy but during combat i could not see the status bar at the bottom. I dont think this is a problem with my hardware because all the run just fine on my vista. Can someone tell me how to fix this I will be grateful ( and if you know how to fix my vista issue it will be of great assistance.)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to run these specific programs reliably and with full access to all of their features, your best option is to return to Windows and try to resolve whatever problems you may have been having with it. Ubuntu is not intended to be a fully functional Windows emulator (nor is any other flavor of Linux), but rather it is a different system with its own programs, which can run **some** Windows applications quite well and others not at all. Even for those program that do work, it can be challenging for a novice to get started with Wine.

Comment: i have just noticed that the problem might be with ocuring with all my windows games some times i only see the action buttons with no word which is turnig out to be a problem with my rpgs where i always need to know my hp, mp, and other stats. some times my hp bar just shows images from the main menu. And dawn of war is not working at all crash after loading screen and its my fav. Please help.